# PHP With MySQL login using password_verify

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

When I try to login in using `password_hash` and `password_verify` it seems to return false all the time.

Here is my code.

```
<-----Login page---->
<?php 

require_once '../../includes/initialize.php';

if($session->is_logged_in()){

    redirect_to("index.php");
}



if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
//Check database to see if username/password exist.

    $found_user = User::authenticate($username, $password);

    if ($found_user) {      
        $session->login($found_user);
        log_action('Login', "{$found_user->username} logged in.");
        redirect_to("index.php");
    }else{

    $message = "Username/Password combination incorrect.";

    }


}else{

    $username = "";
    $password = "";
}

?>

<---Create New Admin Page-->
<?php 

require_once '../../includes/initialize.php';


if(!$session->is_logged_in()){redirect_to("login.php");}

?>

<?php  

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $required_fields = array("first_name", "last_name", "username", "password", "confirm_password");
            validate_presences($required_fields);

            if (empty($errors)) {
                $first_name = trim($_POST['first_name']);
                $last_name = trim($_POST['last_name']);
                $username = trim($_POST['username']);
                $password = trim($_POST['password']);
          $confirm_password= trim($_POST['confirm_password']);

            if ($password != $confirm_password) {
                $message = "Passwords does not match!";
            }else{

          $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 10]);
            $user = new User();
            $user->first_name = $first_name;
            $user->last_name = $last_name;
            $user->username = $username;
            $user->password = $hashed_password;

            if($user->create()){
                $session->message("Admin {$user->username} created successfully.");
                redirect_to('manage_admins.php');
            }else {
                $message = "Admin can't be created!";
            }
        }

        }
    }else{
        $first_name = "";
        $last_name = "";
        $username = "";
    }


?>

<------User Object Page ----->
<?php 

require_once (LIB_PATH.DS.'database.php');

class User extends DatabaseObject{

protected static $table_name = "users";
protected static $db_fields = array('id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name');
public $id;
public $username;
public $password;
public $first_name;
public $last_name;


public function full_name(){
    if(isset($this->first_name) && isset($this->last_name)){

        return $this->first_name." ".$this->last_name;
    }else{

        return "";
    }
}


public static function authenticate($username="", $password=""){

    global $database;
    $username = $database->escape_value($username);
    $password = $database->escape_value($password);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}' LIMIT 1";
    $result_array = self::find_by_sql($sql);
    $admin = !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
    if ($admin) {
      //Found Admin Now check password
      if (password_verify($password, $admin->password)) {
        return $admin;

      }else {
        return false;
      }

    }  

}


}



?>
```

Comment: And what does the `password_verify()` method do?

Comment: 2. Are you sure the problem is not matching the password? Is it finding the username and returning a non-empty `$result_array`, before looking for the password?

Comment: @Aydin password_verify() is a native PHP function to check hashes generated by password_hash()

Comment: Remove `$password = $database->escape_value($password);` It's not necessary there because you don't do the same before calling password_hash.

Comment: $result_array returns all attributes associated with that username, but i want to get only $password that is matching with that username and i compare it with the input password on logging in but when i try self::$password it just blows with error{Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property: User::$password....}

Comment: Try `echo gettype($admin);` right after the `if ($admin) {` line and see if `$admin` is an object or an array.

Comment: @Aydin it outputs object

Comment: And what does your $database->escape_value() do? I replicated this and it worked for me.

Comment: How did you do it bro.Post the code that u changed. Thanks

Comment: I just found it working when i changed the password verify part to login page. Thanks to all of you guys that have helped me. I love you guys